# Lagrange interpolation error.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I've recently started learning about the Lagrange interpolation formula. I've looked into it quite a bit. But some questions arose about the error term 
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1){!}} (x-x_0) \cdots (x-x_n)$$
(where $f$ is the function to interpolate). More precisely about  the function
$$x\to f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))$$
I'm wandering if it's continuous? Continuously differentiable? If it is, how can I show it? I know that 
$$\lim_{x\to x_i}f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))$$
exists (it can be proven by L'Hospital's rule). Other than that, I'm stuck.

---

I've found out that a part of my questions is posed as problem (under Problems 4.2 the 12th) in the book

> Numerical Mathematics and Computing, Sixth edition
>   Ward Cheney, David Kincaid

But the task there asks to prove the continuity. So I'm quite sure that it's continuous. But I still don't know how to prove that.

Comment: What is $f$ in this context ? The function that we want to interpolate ?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is the function to interpolate.

Comment: Please don't clutter the site with extentions of your question. Instead, use the edit command to add more information to your original question, i.e., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749346/307944

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The error in Lagrange interpolation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749346/the-error-in-lagrange-interpolation)

Comment: Removed the duplicate and will use the edit command, thank you for the tip!